# AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute 'has_key'

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have changed my table definitions to use Reference Property. Now when I try to do an insert I get if value is not None and not value.has_key(): AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute 'has_key'

```
subject = self.request.get('subject')
    content = self.request.get('content')
    user = self.request.get('name')
    name = User.all().filter('name =', user)

    if subject and content:
        p = Post(parent = blog_key(), subject = subject, content = content, user = name)

        p.put()
```

This is my Post class

```
class Post(db.Model):
subject = db.StringProperty(required = True)
content = db.TextProperty(required = True)
created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
last_modified = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now = True)
user = db.ReferenceProperty(User)
```

I am using Python 2.7. I have tried to follow the instruction from another posting regarding if value is not None and not value.has_key(): but those suggestions haven't worked for me.

Comment: strange. `has_key` is the deprecated dictionary key check, removed in python 3.

Comment: are you working on python3?

Comment: Oh, I am using Python 2.7 because I think just recently GAE allowed python 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your help.

I added and then set name to p.

```
    for p in q.run():
        print  "name ", p.name

    if subject and content:
        p = Post(parent = blog_key(), subject = subject, content = content, name = p)
```